# chown in dockerfile: What does string after '--chown=' mean?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

In dockerfile:

> ADD --chown=x:y /path/to/a/file /path/in/container

I understand ADD is used for copying files in container. chown is linux way of changing file ownership.

What does the x and y(represented as placeholders here) mean?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for `ADD`: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add?

Comment: chown = Change Owner.  <user>:<group>

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the answer is in the [Dockerfile reference documentation for `ADD` instruction](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add):

> ```
> ADD [--chown=<user>:<group>] [--chmod=<perms>] [--checksum=<checksum>] <src>... <dest>
> ADD [--chown=<user>:<group>] [--chmod=<perms>] ["<src>",... "<dest>"]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

`chown` = "change owner". It's the standard util for changing file owner & group on GNU/Linux.

In `chown x:y /path/to/file`, `x` is the Unix user (user name or UID), and `y` is the Unix group (group name or GID). See https://manned.org/chown.

Here Docker borrows its standard syntax to do the same thing.